# Func<T, TResult> with OrderBy resulting in error with null fields

Tags: linq

I've inherited some code, and also a bug.

The app is a C# MVC website using EF. The VIEW presents clients in a table (taken straight from a CLIENTS table in a SQL Server database).

```
List<Client> _clients = db.Client.ToList();
IEnumerable<Client> filteredClients;
```

The problem arises when the user clicks a header to sort by. The args passed to the controller indicate an index of the field to sort by (sortColumnIndex).

The original dev created a func to handle the translation from the index to the field.

```
Func<Client, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 ? c.Name.ToString() 
                    : sortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.AccountExec.ToString() 
                    : sortColumnIndex == 3 ? c.SalesforceLink.ToString() 
                    : sortColumnIndex == 4 ? c.Location.ToString()
                    : sortColumnIndex == 5 ? c.PrimaryContact.ToString()
                    : sortColumnIndex == 6 ? c.AccountId.ToString()
                    : sortColumnIndex == 6 ? c.MongoClientId.ToString() 
                    : ""); // index 0 is the hidden ClientId
```

The results of this are used in the OrderBy() clause.

```
filteredClients = filteredClients.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
```

When the field being sorted on has complete data (i.e. no NULL values), it works fine. As soon as a column has a NULL value, however, the resulting OrderBy throws a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

I'm afraid I'm not completely up to the task of deciphering the solution here; we still need to sort on the field selected by the user, even if all but one of the records have a NULL value. Is there any way to achieve this with the existing code structure, or is this better served by refactoring?

**EDIT: full code up to the point of exception:**

"param" is the argument that contains all of the filters and such.

```
List<Client> _clients = db.Client.ToList();
IEnumerable<Client> filteredClients;

//Check for filters. This is a search, and we can say it's empty for this purpose
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
{
    var nameFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["bSearch_1"]); // Search string
    var isNameSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_1"]); // Is column searchable? Optional

    filteredClients = _clients.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()));
}
else
{
    filteredClients = _clients.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}

// Sort Column
var isNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_1"]);
var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
Func<Client, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 ? c.Name.ToString() 
    : sortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.AccountExec.ToString() 
    : sortColumnIndex == 3 ? c.SalesforceLink.ToString() 
    : sortColumnIndex == 4 ? c.Location.ToString()
    : sortColumnIndex == 5 ? c.PrimaryContact.ToString()
    : sortColumnIndex == 6 ? c.AccountId.ToString()
    : ""); // index 0 is the hidden ClientId


// Sort Direction
var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc
if (sortDirection == "asc")
{
    //Results of this line generate exception
    filteredClients = filteredClients.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
}
else
{
    filteredClients = filteredClients.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);
}
```

Comment: why do you have 2 sortColumnIndex 6?  Secondly, why are you returning a string, why don't you just passin the IQueryable<Client> and apply the filtering on it with if statements?

Comment: 1. Good question! 2. I inherited this code so I can't say why I was done the way it was done. This is a part of the overall method, though, and there's other filtering applied (such as a search). The original dev split up some of the work, and this is how he chose to deal with the sorting.

Comment: Ah, plus, there's a check for ASC or DESC; I presented the ASC OrderBy, but if the sort is DESC, it uses the same orderingFunction, so I'm assuming "set once, use multiple times" in this case.

Comment: It seems a bit strange that you're getting a null references exception.   Can you show the full code up to where you're getting the null reference exception.

Comment: Also, this code is really weird.  `c.AccountId.ToString()` won't that return the AccountId and not the name of the column? I.E sort by 5 instead of `AccountId`

Answer (score 0):

Well! Thanks to johnny 5's wondering why the c.AccountId.ToString() was in use, I pulled the .ToString() from the func<>, and that seemed to do the trick.

Thanks, johnny 5! Sometimes you just need another set of eyes!